# How can I setup a fixed price (in USD) in a smart-contract?

Tags: contract-design, dapp-development, stablecoins

I would like to sell tokens at a fixed price in dollars and to do the conversion in ETH by default at the coinmarketcap price.
E.g. Would like to sell 1 "mytoken" every day at 1 USD. 1 USD = 0.12 ETH (because the ETH today is quoted at 8.1 USD).

How could I code that?